How to expose a .NET component to COM and use it in Delphi?
Currently, I'm researching how to expose a .NET 8 component to COM in order to make use of it in Delphi. The following steps primarily rely on this MS documentation: Expose .NET Core components to COM.
Right now I got the following .NET code:
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("2D4D3084-E08E-469A-8442-6B3857C84AB9")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IServer
{
    double ComputePi();
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("56986172-C929-44E5-8B67-41B97B7412D8")]
public class Server : IServer
{
    public double ComputePi()
    {
        return Math.PI;
    }
}

I've also enabled COM hosting in my .csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

I then executed the following command to register the COM host for COM:
regsvr32 Netphi.comhost.dll

After that I manually created .idl file looks like this:
[
    uuid(10E262F3-F715-4FA2-A63F-E3ED64134F49),
]
library Netphi
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

    [
        uuid(2D4D3084-E08E-469A-8442-6B3857C84AB9),
    ]
    interface IServer : IUnknown
    {
        [id(1)]
        double ComputePi();
    };

    [
        uuid(56986172-C929-44E5-8B67-41B97B7412D8),
    ]
    coclass Server
    {
        [default] interface IServer;
    };
};

In order to generate the .tlb from the idl, I executed this command:
midl Netphi.idl

This successfully generated my .tlb, which I then imported into Delphi. Delphi automatically builds a wrapper, which I uploaded here on GitHub Gists for simplicity.
I then used the generated wrapper code like this:
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  pServer : TServer;
begin
  pServer := TServer.Create(Self);
  pServer.ComputePi();
end;

In the end, I did all this just to encounter this error:
Class not registered, ClassID: {56986172-C929-44E5-8B67-41B97B7412D8}.

I've already ensured that the COM object is registered in the registry under ``HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID` and I would say, that it looks correct:

Does anybody know why this error occurs and how I could resolve it? I highly appreciate any kind of help!

Edit 1:
As @SimonMourier already said in the comments, the CLSID in question is not in the correct registry. My Delphi application is 32bit. In order to register the COM host correctly for 32bit I did the following:
dotnet publish -r win-x86 -c Release

Then copied the output from ./bin/Release/net8.0/win-x86/publish/ to C:/Windows/SysWoW64/. After that I executed the following command in an elevated command prompt:
C:\Windows\SysWoW64\regsvr32.exe C:\Windows\SysWoW64\Netphi.comhost.dll

which ends up in this error:
The module `C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\Netphi.comhost.dll` was loaded, but the call to `DllRegisterService` was terminated with the error code: 0x80008096.


Edit 2:
Turned out I didn't installed the 32bit .NET 8 sdk. The registration was successful after installing the sdk.
I am now able to start the Delphi application, but I receive some weird errors, probably because of the .tlb. I will probably use the dscom tool to generate the .tlb, since it will probably be more correct than mine.

Class not registered means the client process doesn't see the CLSID in question in the registry. Might want to check x86 vs x64 issues (if you're client is x86 you must register in the x86 registry, if you're client is x64 you must register in x64 registry)

@SimonMourier Thanks for the hint. My Delphi is indeed a 32bit application and I registered the COM host for 64bit. I now get another error. I've edited my question. Again, thank you very much!

@SimonMourier Another edit, another awareness. Just had to install a missing sdk and now everything runs fine. Thank you very much!
